# SciFi book where the enemy aliens were gray and had a mind weapon called the scree

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space

This is a series that I think is pretty old but not sure.  It starts with a guy on Earth and a UFO lands.  A lady falls out obviously in pain and a tiger/lion creature also falls out.  They are being attacked by the quintessential gray aliens with a mind or sound weapon called the scree.  Humans are immune to it.  He helps to save them.  They go off to fight the aliens and he meets many different kinds of races etc.  The lion creatures are the best protectors in the universe.  There is also a tree like race that are super smart and build and end up building all the tech for their war.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions.

Comment: "The Stars in Our Galaxy" in a 1967 edition (volume 26 World Edition) of the Galaxy Science Fiction magazine, bas à promising excerpt via a Google books search, but I can't see the place there, and I can't get the Galaxy message on archive.org to appear intelligibly.

Comment: *I think my translator may have mixed up right with left, too; Do you have the coin?" ' "The scree?" The alien produced it. "Shall there ... No alien could Have guessed what kind of weapon would render him Helpless without killing Him. "I choose ...*

Comment: That quote is from the Niven story There Is A Tide, found in the Tales of Known Space collection. Other than the word scree, there is no resemblance to the story described in the question.

Comment: It might be the Spaceforce series (https://www.amazon.com/Outcaste-Spaceforce-Book-Penelope-Irving-ebook/dp/B0094RZ1WC), but the aliens are named Scree, not their weapons.